# How do I change OSX package install directory?

Tags: macos, installer, packages

It drives me nuts that every time I download a binary to run on OSX that it wants to install in system directories. ~/Applications is a perfectly fine place to install and doesn't require blindly authenticating somebody else's binary.

Is there a way to change the install directory for packages? On a few I've been able to open the package and edit the plist to install it elsewhere, but that doesn't work universally.

I install from source when I can, but it isn't always an option. Is there a good way to force the installer to use ~/Applications?

Comment: If you mean command line applications, you can't.  Unless you mess with the `PATH` environment variable and change up the `.bashrc` file.